# Error executing: /usr/bin/git fetch origin

Tags: git, github, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime text 3

Each time I load the editor i am getting the following error message

> Package Control
>   Error executing:/usr/bin/git fetch origin
>   fatal:could not read Username for 'http://github.com'. Device not
>   configured
>   VCS-based packages can be ignored with the
>   "ignore_vcs_packages" setting.

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and seems like it was caused by the LiveReload package. After uninstalling and re-installing that package via Package Control I didn't get the error message anymore.

I noticed that the LiveReload folder in the `Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` folder included a `.git` folder before the uninstall, and after reinstalling the `.git` folder was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that sublime-text-3-git is using the same installation of git as you get from the command line. If not, you'll see git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. in the echo area when you try to push or pull. In that case you should either delete the other git, or specify in Git.sublime-settings which git to use (find this by going to Preferences>Browse Packages... and opening the "Git" folder). In particular, just set git_command equal to the the output of which git at the command line.

Hope it fix it

Comment: Just checked the packages folder, I dont see a git folder here.

Comment: so it isn't a git problem ok so try set ignore_vcs_packages": true in settings then restart sublime